# Create Issue if search text found in project source in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

In Sonarqube can we able to find an text in project source . If so , it have create an issue with major priority . Is there an rule/rule template exists for text search.

Answer (score 0):

You have rules to do what you want on "Comment" using regular expression : http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#is_template=true|q=Regular%20expression